# Como transformar um JSON em uma tabela/lista paginada utilizando .Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, json, mvc, asp.net-core

Estou estudando acesso a API e estou utilizando a API do Github. Eu quero fazer uma tela na qual seja possível pesquisar por nome os repositórios que batem com o critério passado. Mas os resultados do Github são enormes, como eu posso fazer para paginar essa lista?

Agora estou com problema para ler o JSON retornado pela pesquisa. No código abaixo é a classe que acessa a API e baixa o JSON

```
public List<Repositorio> PesquisaRepo(string repoNome) {
        List<Repositorio> repositorios = new List<Repositorio>();
        string urlPesquisa = urlPesquisaRepo + repoNome;

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", this.userAgent);

        var resposta = client.DownloadString(urlPesquisa);

        var repoJSON = JArray.Parse(resposta);
}
```

Na linha `var repoJSON = JArray.Parse(resposta);` ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array
```

O JSON retornado é nesse formato:

```
    {
  "total_count": 18551,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 76954504,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk3Njk1NDUwNA==",
      "name": "react-tetris",
      "full_name": "chvin/react-tetris",
      "owner": {
        "login": "chvin",
        "id": 5383506,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjUzODM1MDY=",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/5383506?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/chvin",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chvin/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
```

Como eu faço para acessar somente a tag "items"?

A URL que estou acessado é https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris

Comment: poste a parte do código onde está com difilcudade, assim podemos lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi O compilador indica erro

Comment: Voce tem a classe do json ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda A classe para criar objetos com esse JSON? Tenho uma classe chamada Repositorio que tem uns atributos que quero recuperar do JSON

Comment: @Marconi Tentei isso mesmo. Ele diz que "resposta" é uma string e não tem definições para acessar um método

Comment: @LeandroSouza, entendo veja a minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembrando que eu copiei [aqui](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris) e joguei para arquivo txt com codificação de unicode. O resultado do `ReadAllText` é o mesmo que `DownloadString`. Fiz teste apenas no local.

Segue código:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json.txt", Encoding.Unicode);

RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

var somente_tag_items = result.items;
```

Caso você queira pesquisar pelo Id (2548674), faça assim:

```
var items = result.items.Where(x => x.id == 2548674).ToList();
```

Segue as classes:

```
public class Owner
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string gravatar_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public string followers_url { get; set; }
    public string following_url { get; set; }
    public string gists_url { get; set; }
    public string starred_url { get; set; }
    public string subscriptions_url { get; set; }
    public string organizations_url { get; set; }
    public string repos_url { get; set; }
    public string events_url { get; set; }
    public string received_events_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool site_admin { get; set; }
}

public class License
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string spdx_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
    public bool @private { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool fork { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string forks_url { get; set; }
    public string keys_url { get; set; }
    public string collaborators_url { get; set; }
    public string teams_url { get; set; }
    public string hooks_url { get; set; }
    public string issue_events_url { get; set; }
    public string events_url { get; set; }
    public string assignees_url { get; set; }
    public string branches_url { get; set; }
    public string tags_url { get; set; }
    public string blobs_url { get; set; }
    public string git_tags_url { get; set; }
    public string git_refs_url { get; set; }
    public string trees_url { get; set; }
    public string statuses_url { get; set; }
    public string languages_url { get; set; }
    public string stargazers_url { get; set; }
    public string contributors_url { get; set; }
    public string subscribers_url { get; set; }
    public string subscription_url { get; set; }
    public string commits_url { get; set; }
    public string git_commits_url { get; set; }
    public string comments_url { get; set; }
    public string issue_comment_url { get; set; }
    public string contents_url { get; set; }
    public string compare_url { get; set; }
    public string merges_url { get; set; }
    public string archive_url { get; set; }
    public string downloads_url { get; set; }
    public string issues_url { get; set; }
    public string pulls_url { get; set; }
    public string milestones_url { get; set; }
    public string notifications_url { get; set; }
    public string labels_url { get; set; }
    public string releases_url { get; set; }
    public string deployments_url { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime pushed_at { get; set; }
    public string git_url { get; set; }
    public string ssh_url { get; set; }
    public string clone_url { get; set; }
    public string svn_url { get; set; }
    public string homepage { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public int stargazers_count { get; set; }
    public int watchers_count { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public bool has_issues { get; set; }
    public bool has_projects { get; set; }
    public bool has_downloads { get; set; }
    public bool has_wiki { get; set; }
    public bool has_pages { get; set; }
    public int forks_count { get; set; }
    public object mirror_url { get; set; }
    public bool archived { get; set; }
    public int open_issues_count { get; set; }
    public License license { get; set; }
    public int forks { get; set; }
    public int open_issues { get; set; }
    public int watchers { get; set; }
    public string default_branch { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public bool incomplete_results { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada, estamos aqui pra isso.